# Calculate a function with logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

I have to build a circuit, with logic gates, that calculates a function \$f(n) = 2^{2^n}\$ where n is a 4 bit number. I can't figure a way how to do this. I tried to use 2-to-4 decoders but I failed. Can someone help me with an idea?

Comment: It's very hard for us to help you if we don't know how much you know. Can you show us what you've tried with the decoders so far?

Comment: I used 2 2to4 decoders, so in this way i have 4 inputs but only 8 outputs. But with 8 outputs I can't have all the solutions for 2^2^n. I think that i need 32 outputs?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a diagram for this circuit. I have only the task. Like I said I tried with 2 decoders but this can't display all the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Do \$2^N\$ first.

For \$2^N\$ you need a 4 bit to 1 of 16 decoder.

You can make one using 2 74LS138 3 bit to 1 of 8 decoders.

\$2^{2^N}\$ can be done by just re-labeling the outputs!

Comment: Do you have a diagram of this circuit because I can figure out  how is this done?

Comment: Keep in mind that \$2^{2^{15}}\$ is a number that contains 32769 bits, most of which are zero ...

Comment: @johndoe http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/sn74ls138rev5.pdf page 2, that and what Dave said

Comment: @Jasen what do you mean by re-labeling the outputs?

Comment: @JohnDoe For renaming It should be obvious what changes you need to make: just compare the produced, and desired bit patterns,  the logic values you need for the 2^2^n result are either present in the 2^n  result or always 0, they just need to be renamed.